# QNetworkAccessManager memory issues

Tags: c++, qt, qnetworkaccessmanager, qnetworkreply

I am developing an application that sends requests to a server using QtNetworkAccessManager and stores the replies. I've made it work but the memory usage is increasing continuosly until and it block the whole PC. I think the problem is related with calling deletelater() and the event loop, but I can't see how to fix it. Here is the code:

main.cpp

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    ReadConfig();
    Ethernet M2;
    return a.exec();
}
```

Ethernet.h

```
class Ethernet : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Ethernet();
    ~Ethernet();
    QTimer *timer;

private
    QNetworkAccessManager *manager;

public slots:
    void Cycle();
    void replyAuthenticationRequired(QNetworkReply *reply, QAuthenticator *auth);
    void replyFinished(QNetworkReply *reply);
};
```

Ethernet.cpp

```
Ethernet::Ethernet() 
{
    timer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(Cycle()));
    timer->start(1000);

    manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    connect(manager, SIGNAL(authenticationRequired(QNetworkReply*,QAuthenticator*)), this, SLOT(replyAuthenticationRequired(QNetworkReply*,QAuthenticator*)));
    connect(manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this,     SLOT(replyFinished(QNetworkReply*)));
}

void Ethernet::Cycle()
{
    for (BYTE i=0; i< NUM_TOTAL_VEHICLES; i++)
    {
        FailCheck(i,FILTER_VALUE_PRIORITY_A1);
        FailCheck(i,FILTER_VALUE_PRIORITY_A);
        FailCheck(i,FILTER_VALUE_PRIORITY_B);
        FailCheck(i,FILTER_VALUE_PRIORITY_C);
    }
}

void Ethernet::FailCheck (BYTE coach, BYTE priority)
{
    //Build a valid URL
    QString qsURL = "http://";
    ...
    ..
    .
    //

    manager->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl(qsURL)));
}

void Ethernet::replyAuthenticationRequired(QNetworkReply *reply, QAuthenticator *auth)
{
   if(!reply->error())
   {
       auth->setUser(DB_USR);
       auth->setPassword(DB_PWD);
   }
   reply->deleteLater();
}

void Ethernet::replyFinished (QNetworkReply *reply)
{
    if(!reply->error())
    {
        //Do some task with the reply;
    }
    reply->deleteLater();
}
```

I will appreciate any suggestions. Thank you!

Comment: you have no event loop in your Ethernet class, so deleteLater - not working

Comment: The code you posted can't be compiled, your `Ethernet` class has slots and `Q_OBJECT` macro but doesn't inherit `QObject`, what is your actual code?

Comment: Thank you for your answers. My Ethernet class inherits from QThread because it used to be a thread but not anymore. So the real implementation of the class is `class Ethernet :: public QThread`. I've corrected in the main post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your class is not a thread then it should not inherit `QThread`. Inherit it from `QObject` or, if you can't, start your `M2` thread. Right now your thread loop for the `Ethernet` doesn't work <s>and it seems like the network replies have an affinity to your `Ethernet` event loop(the requests to delete them are posted to the `Ethernet` event loop, which is not started)</s>.

Or rather, your slots are never executed at all, so the network replies get created but they will never have a chance to be deleted since your slots never executed(because of the said reason) so if I'm not mistaken the network replies live in the main thread so `deleteLater` should correctly delete them but it is never called.

Comment: I've modified the Ethernet class to `class Ethernet : public QObject` but the problem is still there.

Comment: @Puccinih, make sure you did a clean build and that `replyAuthenticationRequired` and `replyFinished` slots get called

Comment: The slots were called from the beginning, but it is true that only a few times. Now, after change the inheritance of the class to QObject and make a clean build it seems to be solved. I'll do some further testing with the server to see if it really works fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to subclass Ethernet from QObject to use event loop properly

Comment: He calls `QCoreApplication::exec()`, which starts the event loop.

Comment: @KarstenKoop if your class not subclassed from QObject it can't use event loop

Comment: Event loop is not object-related so your answer is misleading — you don't need to subclass anything to use an event loop

Answer (score 0):

You must not make multiple objects of QNetworkAccessManager. As the document says "One QNetworkAccessManager should be enough for the whole Qt application."
[Reference link](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html). If you make multiple object of Ethernet class then it will create a memory issue. And you also need to make QObject as Ethernet's base class.

```
manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
this (Ethernet) must have QObject as base class.
```